# Are electric zaps effective for exercising?

Tags: electromagnetism

I've seen commercials of "TENS" (Transcutaneous electrical nerve stimulation) devices that you strap on to your stomach or thighs, which zaps you continuously making your muscles contract, supposedly burning calories.

I'm somewhat of a lazy tub myself, so if this worked it would be a miracle device; slimming me down and working on my six pack whilst I'm at work programming.

Obviously I'm highly skeptical of this wonder-machine, hence [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)

Open fire!

Comment: unlinkable (on an old tv show) study on very small set (2 testees and 2 controls IIRC) I recall showed that it would tone muscles but doesn't burn extra calories (it's no cardio/endurance training). In other words you won't lose weight but muscles would become more defined

Comment: Low levels of electricity can be used to activate muscles, but high levels of electricity can also cause permanent damage (e.g., the electric chair used to execute criminals).  These products are targeting lazy people who want to exercise without getting off the couch, and I'd worry that pro-longed use of these low-power devices to exercise might cause damage to muscles at a very slow rate.

Comment: What causes the muscle to work doesn't really matter for the effects. The differences are in how the muscle works and how much. In other words, for this to burn calories in the same way as exercise, it has to make the muscles work the same way as exercise and this will feel like exercise. Most notable, you'll get just as tired. This devices also will likely use much fewer muscles than exercising, meaning these few muscles have to work very hard. If you want to burn calories while programming, I suggest working on an exercise bike. :-) (No, I haven't tried it).

Comment: @Randolf The claim that this targets lazy people isn’t entirely correct. It is also used in medical scenarios (rehabilitation) and sports. Of course, that doesn’t mean that it actually works (though I suspect it does).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph:  I agree (+1), but I just can't imagine a medical professional buying these products from infomercials.

Comment: I used Miha bodytech electro muscle stimulation for 6 months 3 times a week 50 minute sessions. I stopped one month ago after I had my appendicitis abrupted and a peritonitis operation

Comment: Anecdotally, something like this was *part* of my physical therapy for a torn rotator cuff (IIRC about 20 minutes per session, 3 times per week). The physical therapy worked very well for me, although I was always skeptical about the "zap" part's contribution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From [Vanderbilt University](http://healthpsych.psy.vanderbilt.edu/AbSonic.htm):

> There is no doubt in the medical
> community that it is possible to
> transcutaneously, that is, through the
> skin, stimulate nerves.
>
> A variation
> of EMS (*electrical muscle stimulation*) is *transcutaneous electrical
> nerve stimulation* (TENS). TENS is a
> pain management system that uses less
> intense shocks to block pain signals.
>
> **The question about EMS is can
> it really burn enough calories to
> reduce a waistline, decrease body fat,
> and strengthen muscles?**

...

> **A full research study was conducted at
> the University of Wisconsin** and
> published in 2002 by "[Porcari et al](http://www.hawaii.edu/hivandaids/Effects%20of%20Electrical%20Muscle%20Stimulation%20on%20Body%20Composition,%20Muscle%20Strength.pdf)".
>
> The study was to test the claims of
> EMS manufactures on there marketing of
> "rock-hard abs" and other weight loss
> claims.
>
> **They took 29 college aged students**
> that had not been in a formal exercise
> program within the past 6 months and
> **assigned them to either a treatment
> EMS group or a control group that was
> given faulty EMS equipment**.
>
> The groups came in to **use it 3 times
> per week for 8 weeks**.
>
> The subjects used the device on five muscle groups:
>
> - bilateral biceps
> - triceps
> - quadriceps
> - hamstrings
> - abdominal muscles
>
> [image: muscle groups]

### Results:

> The results showed **no significant
> changes in weight, percent body fat,
> girth or strength** of the treatment
> areas.
>
> **The EMS device did not work
> for any of the claims.**
>
> [image: table 1]
> [image: table 2]

---

**In the United States EMS devices are regulated by the [FDA](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cms_ia/importalert_240.html):**

> The use of these electrical devices in
> health clubs, beauty salons and figure
> salons has been increasing for several
> years.
>
> **While there are legitimate uses
> for both muscle stimulators and
> iontophoresis devices, they are
> prescription devices and are
> misbranded when labeled for lay use**.
>
> In addition, **muscle stimulators are
> misbranded when any of the following
> claims are made**:
>
> - girth reduction
> - loss of inches
> - weight reduction
> - cellulite removal
> - bust development
> - body shaping and contouring
> - spot reducing

Comment: +1 Excellent!  I particularly liked the last part that includes the FDA's statement about these being misbranded [medical] prescription devices -- it would be good to see more enforcement to stop the marketers though, especially when they get on TV infomercials.

Comment: It makes sense that these wouldn't work - when you exercise manually, you are using your own energy to power your muscles. With these devices, your muscles are only contracting because of stimulation from an external power source. People are deceived in thinking that muscle contraction = burning calories, but they fail to realize that those calories being burned aren't their own - they're from the batteries in the device.

Comment: @Tesserex: I don't think that's true; muscles don't contract using electrical energy, it's a mechanical process in the fibers.

Comment: Just to add to what user1770 - muscles (like the rest of the body) get their energy by turning oxygen and glucose from the blood into carbon dioxide and water.